# Firewall tool for Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm looking for a tool that can block applications from accessing the Internet, an alternate Windows Firewall Tool.

Features Required:

- Simple and Easy to Use
- Light-weight
- Able to block applications from accessing the internet
- Preferably Open-Source or Premium is also fine.

Comment: It seems to me that Windows' own firewall can do that; what additional features do you need?

Comment: Windows firewall has lots of bugs, It crashes with no reasons. Maybe a problem with my PC. And I'm not sure how to block applications from accessing Internet in Windows Firewall

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Program-with-Windows-Firewall  This is the correct site to ask for a new firewall. To get the Windows firewall working, ask on https://superuser.com/ Good luck :-)